How to change the dashes in arydshln package?
All I am finding is that \dashlinegap and \dashlinedash are style parameters that can change the dash length and spacing, but not how to use them. I have no idea where in my .tex file to put them, or whether they work in certain environments, nothing! Do they take arguments? Are there limitations in what kind of numbers they can use? Please enlighten me! If it matters, I am using TeX Live 2024 on Windows, pdfLaTeX.

\dashlinedash and \dashlinegap are both lengths that you can adjust using \setlength. Their defaults are both 4pt. Here are some examples on how to adjust them if you want:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l : : c ;{2pt/2pt} r | }
  \hline
  A   &  B  &   C \\
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \cdashline{1-2}[.4pt/1pt]
  \multicolumn{2}{ | l ;{2pt/2pt} }{AB} & C \\
  \hdashline\hdashline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begingroup
\setlength{\dashlinedash}{2\dashlinedash}% Locally change \dashlinedash to twice its original length

\begin{tabular}{ | l : : c ;{2pt/2pt} r | }
  \hline
  A   &  B  &   C \\
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \cdashline{1-2}[.4pt/1pt]
  \multicolumn{2}{ | l ;{2pt/2pt} }{AB} & C \\
  \hdashline\hdashline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begingroup
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{0.5\dashlinegap}% Locally reduce \dashlinegap to half its length

\begin{tabular}{ | l : : c ;{2pt/2pt} r | }
  \hline
  A   &  B  &   C \\
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \cdashline{1-2}[.4pt/1pt]
  \multicolumn{2}{ | l ;{2pt/2pt} }{AB} & C \\
  \hdashline\hdashline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begingroup
\setlength{\dashlinedash}{5pt}% Manually update \dashlinedash
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{10pt}% Manually update \dashlinegap

\begin{tabular}{ | l : : c ;{2pt/2pt} r | }
  \hline
  A   &  B  &   C \\
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \cdashline{1-2}[.4pt/1pt]
  \multicolumn{2}{ | l ;{2pt/2pt} }{AB} & C \\
  \hdashline\hdashline
\end{tabular}

\endgroup

\end{document}

As you can see, you can adjust these lengths proportionally (via <num><length>, which multiplies <length> by the factor <num>), or using fixed lengths. Their setting only affects :-style column separation and \hdashline/\cdashline horizontal rules set without their optional arguments.
